# Difference between !empty($x) and @$x?

Tags: php

Is there any functional difference between `if(!empty($x))` and `if(@$x)`?

N.B. I'm aware that `@` suppresses errors, and I don't use it lightly.

Comment: Didn't you just answer your own question?

Comment: I've never seen the `if(@$x)` idiom. Is it common?

Comment: I think there would be no functional difference between if(isset($x)) and if(@$x) for that matter as well though. I'm interested in testing this out :p

Comment: @rosscowar: There is a difference. `isset()` only check if it's defined and non-null. `empty` also checks for truthiness.

Comment: I guess you’re missing a `!` somewhere. Besides that, have a look at the [type comparison tables](http://php.net/types.comparisons).

Comment: Yeah I wasn't sure because empty always generates a warning when it's not set on top of being empty.

Comment: @TecBrat: No; I don't think so. I haven't seen it used elsewhere, but I started doing it with GET/POST vars when I just don't care if the value is submitted or not.

Comment: @Gumbo: Good catch Corrected.

Comment: @Gumbo: Looks like they're exact opposites... which I guess answers the question.

Comment: When I saw this, my first thought was: this just looks wrong. Thinking about it for 5 mins now and I still can't think of a reason why it would be wrong... interesting question Mark.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There may be no functional difference as others have pointed out but using `if(@$x)` just doesn't seem right and there is reason why not to use it.

From documentation about [suppression error operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php):

> If you have set a custom error handler function with set_error_handler() then it will still get called, but this custom error handler can (and should) call error_reporting() which will return 0 when the call that triggered the error was preceded by an @.

and in one comment from same page someone wrote:

> I was confused as to what the @ symbol actually does, and after a few experiments have concluded the following:
>
> - the error handler that is set gets called regardless of what level the error reporting is set on, or whether the statement is preceeded
>     with @
> - it is up to the error handler to impart some meaning on the different error levels. You could make your custom error handler echo
>     all errors, even if error reporting is set to NONE.
> - so what does the @ operator do? It temporarily sets the error reporting level to 0 for that line. If that line triggers an error,
>     the error handler will still be called, but it will be called with an
>     error level of 0
>
> Hope this helps someone

In short, You may not see any difference but there is some extra work behind scenes if You use `if(@$x)` instead of [isset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) and [empty](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php).
That is because error handler is called always, even if You suppress errors.

Comment: I'd consider that a functional difference, and an important one at that. Thanks for bringing this up!

Comment: A great catch, I imagine the error handler being called multiple times when it isn't necessary will make quite some difference to the stack. More so when using a framework such as Symfony or Laravel where the error handlers arent particularly light (in comparison to native).

Answer (score 2):

I ran the series of tests and came back with these results.

```
When $x="foo";

@$x == true
!empty($x) == true
isset($x) == true

When $x has not been set!

@$x == false
!empty($x) == false
isset($x) == false
```

Here's another set with a different x value.

```
When $x=0;

@$x == false
!empty($x) == false
isset($x) == true
```

and again with 1.

```
When $x=1;

@$x == true
!empty($x) == true
isset($x) == true
```

Comment: Well I know you knew the answer but for completeness ;)

Comment: I even tried it with literal booleans and I still see no functional difference between !empty($x) and @$x

Answer (score 1):

Was quite curious about this, the results of some tests I ran showed no deviations at all.

Tests in format:

```
var_dump(!empty($x));
var_dump(!!@$x);
```

Results

```
$x is an empty array
boolean false
boolean false

$x is int(1)
boolean true
boolean true

$x is int(0)
boolean false
boolean false

$x is float(0.1)
boolean true
boolean true

$x is string(0)
boolean false
boolean false

$x is string(1)
boolean true
boolean true

$x is string(abc)
boolean true
boolean true

$x is instance of stdClass
boolean true
boolean true

$x is true
boolean true
boolean true

$x is false
boolean false
boolean false

$x is defined null
boolean false
boolean false

$x is not set
boolean false
boolean false
```